# PHP Forms Submit Button/Submit to Database

Tags: php

All I'm trying to do is generate a form with text input fields and buttons in the coding style below. Everything is working fine, but I'm kind of confused as to how to generate a submit button, and upon submit, insert the data from the text fields into a database.  How would I correctly generate a submit button using the coding style below?

IceCreamForm.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'Form.php';
require_once 'RadioButton.php';
require_once 'TextInput.php';
require_once 'Validator.php';

$form = new Form();

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("First Name: ", "firstName"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Last Name: ", "lastName"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Ice Cream Flavor: ", "iceCreamFlavor"));

$radio = new RadioButton("Number of Scoops: ");
$radio -> addOption("One Scoop", "one");
$radio -> addOption("Two Scoops", "two");
$radio -> addOption("Three Scoops", "three");
$form -> addInput($radio);

echo $form -> generateHTML();
```

Form.php:

```
<?php

class Form
{
    const GET = "GET";
    const POST = "POST";
    private $action = "someLocation.php";
    private $inputs = array();
    private $method = "POST";
    public $form = "";
    public $name = "";

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function addInput(TextInput $input)
    {
        $this -> inputs[] = $input;
    }

    function getAction(): string
    {
        return $this -> action;
    }

    function getMethod(): string
    {
        return $this -> method;
    }

    function setAction(string $action)
    {
        $this -> action = $action;
        return $this;
    }

    function setMethod(string $method)
    {
        $this -> method = $method;
        return $this;
    }

    function set($param, $value)
    {
        $this -> $param = $value;
    }

    function generateHTML(): string
    {
        $this -> form = '<form action="' . $this -> getAction() . '" 
        method="' . $this -> getMethod() . '">';
        foreach ($this -> inputs as $input)
        {
            $this -> form .= $input -> generateHTML();
        }

        $this -> form .= '</form>';

        return $this -> form;
    }
}
```

TextInput.php:

```
<?php

    class TextInput
    {
        const TYPE = "text";
        private static $REQUIRED = "REQUIRED";
        private $defaultValue;
        private $id;
        private $label;
        private $name;
        private $onNewLine;
        private $required = false;
        private $type;

        function __construct($label = "", $name = "", $defaultValue = "", $id = "", $onNewLine = "", $required = false, $type = self::TYPE)
        {
            $this -> defaultValue = $defaultValue;
            $this -> id = $id;
            $this -> label = $label;
            $this -> name = $name;
            $this -> onNewLine = $onNewLine;
            $this -> required = $required;
            $this -> type = $type;
        }

        public function generateHTML():string
        {
            $req = "";

            if ($this -> required == true)
            {
                $req = self::$REQUIRED;
            }

            return "<label>$this->label</label><input id='$this->id' type='$this->type' name='$this->name' onNewLine='$this->onNewLine' $req/><br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might as well add another input, which is the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make below changes:

Change the `generateHTML()` method of TextInput class to add the `defaultValue`.

```
public function generateHTML():string
{
    $req = "";

    if ($this -> required == true)
    {
        $req = self::$REQUIRED;
    }

    return "<label>$this->label</label><input id='$this->id' type='$this->type' name='$this->name' onNewLine='$this->onNewLine' value='$this -> defaultValue' $req/><br/>";
}
```

create submit button as below:

```
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("", "submit_btn","Submit Button Name","submit_btn","",false,"submit"));
```

to save the data add form action and method as

```
echo $form -> setAction("You post url where you want to save data");
echo $form -> setMethod("POST");
echo $form -> generateHTML();
```